# Accordion in HTML not working with table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble with an accordion within a table. The code below is what outputs the accordion and HTML layout 
echo '';

```
              echo '<td>';

                 echo'<div class="accordion-heading">';

                echo'<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="'.$string1.'">';

              echo '<strong>'.$data->Title.'</strong>';

                echo'</a>';

               echo'</div>';


             echo '</td>';



           echo '<td>';
           echo $data->Type;
          echo '</td>';

           echo '<td>';
          echo $data->ID;
       echo '</td>';




    echo'<div id="'.$string2.'" class="accordion-body collapse">';

               echo'<div class="accordion-inner">';                     

                    echo 'Test';

             echo'</div>';

    echo'</div>';

echo '</tr>';
```

The problem with this is that the 'Test' expandable box is expanding at the top of the page, not below the table's TR where it should be.

Comment: Can we see the real HTML? This is somewhat difficult to visualize

Comment: Heres the rendered HTML http://pastebin.com/cJsxyU17

Comment: Breh. JSFiddle it up broski.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Guys, maybe he doesn't know what JSFiddle is!  http://www.jsfiddle.net